# Java construct new ArrayList without deep clone

Tags: java, arraylist

I got a question about constructing a new `ArrayList` based on an already existing list, I need it to reverse a `List`. I do not need to deep clone the elements, since I only inspect their values and do not change them.

My old, working, code, it seems a bit hackish to me, so I think I had problems with it in the past:

```
        Collections.sort(invoiceWordGroups, new WordGroup.WordGroupComparator());
        insertAttributes(topAttributeWords, invoiceWordGroups, templateId, templateAttributeManager, invoiceMarginDataVAT);
        Collections.reverse(invoiceWordGroups);
        insertAttributes(bottomAttributeWords, invoiceWordGroups, templateId, templateAttributeManager, invoiceMarginDataVAT);
```

My new code, I will test it aswell ofcourse, but even then some errors might remain to be in there, if my basic concepts are not oK. So would this have the same behaviour?

```
        Collections.sort(invoiceWordGroups, new WordGroup.WordGroupComparator());
        List<WordGroup> invoiceWordGroupsReverse = new ArrayList<>(invoiceWordGroups);
        Collections.reverse(invoiceWordGroupsReverse);
        insertAttributes(topAttributeWords, invoiceWordGroups, templateId, templateAttributeManager, invoiceMarginDataVAT);
        insertAttributes(bottomAttributeWords, invoiceWordGroupsReverse, templateId, templateAttributeManager, invoiceMarginDataVAT);
```

The question is about `invoiceWordGroups`, which is of type `List<WordGroup>`. The reason I am changing it is because I will need to use the lists multiple times now, and constantly reversing it does definately not seem to be a good option.

Comment: what exactly is the question? If changing "invoiceWordGroups" will impact "invoiceWordGroupsReverse" and vice versa?

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk The question is whether both pieces of code have the same behaviour or not. So essentially if the `Collections.reverse()` reverses (unexpectedly) both lists, or just the one I want to reverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the Java source code the copy constructor for ArrayList creates a **new list object which copies (hence the name copy constructor) the internal array (but even though it's a copy of the original array it still points to the same elements!!!).** This internal array object is not shared therefore and it is the object which is responsible for what a given list object actually stores and in what order:

```
   public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
       elementData = c.toArray();
       size = elementData.length;
       // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
       if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
           elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
   }
```

So reversing one list **won't** affect the order of the other. Same goes for adding/deleting elements from one list or the other.

You said that those are read-only objects then it will be ok but remember that even though both lists are different objects they **still point to the same elements**, so changing the state of object X in list1 will also be shown when accessing that object X with list2.